# ADF flow losses current row selection

Tags: oracle, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 and I have this issue.
I'll try to explain the best I can.

I have a flow. The first view, named *mainTable.jspx*, has a table with current data and a *New Data* button.
Each row in table has a *setCurrentRowWithKey* link to Edit the selected data. With this link, current row is selected.

- Edit link action is *edit* flow, which navegates to *editData.jspx*
- New Data button action is *new* flow, which navegates to *Create* operation and then to *editData.jspx* with empty fields.

The *editData.jspx* behaviour is right, so it has empty fields with *new* flow or fulfilled fields with *edit* flow.

In *editData.jspx* I have a custom button *Check* with an action. I make some checks, so if there is an error, I show an error message with FacesContext.addMessage. This button makes no *Delete*, *Commit* or *Rollback* operation.

Well, my issue arises with these steps:

- Go to *mainTable.jspx*
- Click *Edit* link in a row
- Go to *editData.jspx*
- Click *Check* button. One check is not ok, so an error message is displayed. By now, next wrong steps happen.
- Current selection data removes, and previous data row from the table is shown in *editData.jspx*
- When I click *Back* button to come back to the table in mainTable.jspx, the initial row selected in step 2 is not shown in the table.
- In database, all data exist, even the *ghost* data.

I don't know what is happening. There is no *Delete*, *Commit* or *Rollback* operation in the problematic button.

How can I fix this? Is there something I'm not doing right in the flow?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Might want to post your code, but a wild guess would be to create an object in your backing bean to store 'selectedRowKeys'.

Comment: When you press the check button, does it fire "execute" operation?

Comment: @patrick-j-abare-ii, thank you for your suggestions. Now I'll explain the solution; some parts in my *some checks* section are not well done.

Comment: @amr-gawish, , thank you for your suggestions. Now I'll explain the solution; some parts in my some checks section are not well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue happened because a bad use of iterators.

In *some checks* of my explanation, some steps are getting current row from an iterator, and reuse the same iterator to get another rowset by *executeQuery*, so current row was lost and it implied an inconsistent state.

The solution is to create another different iterator, from the same view, but a different iterator with different name. So, the *main* iterator keeps current row, and other additional operationes, queries, etc. are made by *different* iterator.

Hope it helps. Regards